# Is this the most efficient way to get and remove first line in file?

Tags: php, file

I have a script which, each time is called, gets the first line of a file. Each line is known to be exactly of the same length (32 alphanumeric chars) and terminates with "\r\n".
After getting the first line, the script removes it.

This is done in this way:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file));
$first_line = substr($contents, 0, 32);
file_put_contents($file, substr($contents, 32 + 2)); //+2 because we remove also the \r\n
```

Obviously it works, but I was wondering whether there is a smarter (or more efficient) way to do this?

In my simple solution I basically **read and rewrite the entire file just to take and remove the first line**.

Comment: You can make this more efficient in memory (do a loop, read one line at a time, write them out one at a time except for the first one), but it will look convoluted and will be error-prone. I'd do the same as you. There's no getting around the fact that files are stored sequentially, starting from the first byte.

Comment: if you could store the file as an indexed, and perform all R/W through the index, perhaps this operation would be faster as you can just simply remove that line from the index and doing so would be cheaper than doing this operation on a complete file. 

However if the file is small then cost of I/O would be less than the overhead of maintaining the index.

Comment: The only highly optimal solution to a similar problem that I can think of would involve an IOCTL in the file system driver that would snip the first logical block (of hardware- and implementation-dependent size) from the file without touching the rest. But this is an academic excercise in solving the nonexistent problem, and definitely not what you're after. :)

Comment: ###why not Replace "32 + 2" with "34" on line 3.### it might help by a few milliseconds, or more if you're doing this repeatedly. Sorry this couldn't be a comment (I don't have a enough reputation).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no more efficient way to do this other than rewriting the file.

Answer (score 28):

I came up with this idea yesterday:

```
function read_and_delete_first_line($filename) {
  $file = file($filename);
  $output = $file[0];
  unset($file[0]);
  file_put_contents($filename, $file);
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: You still read and rewrite the entrie file, but I admit it's a little bit better. +1

Comment: How large are we talking about?

Answer (score 13):

No need to create a second temporary file, nor put the whole file in memory:

```
if ($handle = fopen("file", "c+")) {             // open the file in reading and editing mode
    if (flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {               // lock the file, so no one can read or edit this file 
        while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== FALSE) { 
            if (!isset($write_position)) {        // move the line to previous position, except the first line
                $write_position = 0;
            } else {
                $read_position = ftell($handle); // get actual line
                fseek($handle, $write_position); // move to previous position
                fputs($handle, $line);           // put actual line in previous position
                fseek($handle, $read_position);  // return to actual position
                $write_position += strlen($line);    // set write position to the next loop
            }
        }
        fflush($handle);                         // write any pending change to file
        ftruncate($handle, $write_position);     // drop the repeated last line
        flock($handle, LOCK_UN);                 // unlock the file
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some short comments next to code to explain what you are doing?!

Comment: This code just doesn't work, it simply overwrites lines in place. See working version based on this one in the [answer by Marcos Fernandez Ramo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404707/is-this-the-most-efficent-way-to-get-and-remove-first-line-in-file/23269245#23269245)

Answer (score 6):

This will shift the first line of a file, you dont need to load the entire file in memory like you do using the 'file' function. Maybe for small files is a bit more slow than with 'file' (maybe but i bet is not) but is able to manage largest files without problems.

```
$firstline = false;
if($handle = fopen($logFile,'c+')){
    if(!flock($handle,LOCK_EX)){fclose($handle);}
    $offset = 0;
    $len = filesize($logFile);
    while(($line = fgets($handle,4096)) !== false){
        if(!$firstline){$firstline = $line;$offset = strlen($firstline);continue;}
        $pos = ftell($handle);
        fseek($handle,$pos-strlen($line)-$offset);
        fputs($handle,$line);
        fseek($handle,$pos);
    }
    fflush($handle);
    ftruncate($handle,($len-$offset));
    flock($handle,LOCK_UN);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Is it somehow better than the [answer by Edakos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404707/is-this-the-most-efficent-way-to-get-and-remove-first-line-in-file/20908373#20908373)?

Comment: I made it because I was unable to make Edakos solution to work correctly. In line 3 there is a erroneous "continue" though.

Comment: Indeed, code in that answer doesn't work. +1 to you.

Comment: @MarcosFernandezRamos why don't edit and remove the erroneous "continue" ? instead of using a comment to mention it...

Comment: @발렌텐 lazyness I suppose

Comment: In case you try to run this snippet *multiple times* in a single server call, remember that `filesize()` can return a cached value. Run `clearstatcache()` before each call if this is the case.

Answer (score 5):

you can iterate the file , instead of putting them all in memory

```
$handle = fopen("file", "r");
$first = fgets($handle,2048); #get first line.
$outfile="temp";
$o = fopen($outfile,"w");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle,2048);
    fwrite($o,$buffer);
}
fclose($handle);
fclose($o);
rename($outfile,$file);
```

Comment: +1: I think this is more memory efficient, but not more fast. Certantly it won't blow up if the file is too big to fit in memory.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't usually recommend opening up a shell for this sort of thing, but if you're doing this infrequently on really large files, there's probably something to be said for:

```
$lines = `wc -l myfile` - 1;
`tail -n $lines myfile > newfile`;
```

It's simple, and it doesn't involve reading the whole file into memory.

I wouldn't recommend this for small files, or extremely frequent use though.  The overhead's too high.

Comment: This isn't efficient in anyway and also the code isn't portable

Comment: For, say, a 3 gigabyte file, this'll be a lot more efficient than most of the answers posted here.  Most of the posted answers will die with out of memory errors on large files.  You're right that it isn't portable though.  There's a very specific set of circumstances in which this solution would be useful/acceptable.

Comment: Would be nice to get some comments on this one, im proficient in linux and still having trouble with this one. ty

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
$contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$first_line = array_shift($contents);
file_put_contents($file, implode("\r\n", $contents));
```

There's countless other ways to do that also, but all the methods would involve separating the first line somehow and saving the rest. You cannot avoid rewriting the whole file. An alternative take:

```
list($first_line, $contents) = explode("\r\n", file_get_contents($file), 2);
file_put_contents($file, implode("\r\n", $contents));
```

Comment: Your first example will generate redundant newlines. Without the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag for `file()` you don't need to `implode()` the lines with newlines again.

Comment: Ulman: +1 very interesting code, thanks! I never used file function before.

Answer (score 2):

You could store positional info into the file itself. For example, the first 8 bytes of the file could store an integer. This integer is the byte offset of the first real line in the file.

So, you never delete lines anymore. Instead, deleting a line means altering the start position. fseek() to it and then read lines as normal.

The file will grow big eventually. You could periodically clean up the orphaned lines to reduce the file size.

But seriously, just use a database and don't do stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was large files.  I just needed to edit, or remove the first line.  This was a solution I used.  Didn't require to load the complete file in a variable.  Currently echos, but you could always save the contents.

```
$fh = fopen($local_file, 'rb');
echo "add\tfirst\tline\n";  // add your new first line.
fgets($fh); // moves the file pointer to the next line.
echo stream_get_contents($fh); // flushes the remaining file.
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is best for any file size**

```
$myfile = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$ch=1;

while(!feof($myfile)) {
  $dataline= fgets($myfile) . "<br>";
  if($ch == 2){
  echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $dataline)."\n";
  }
  $ch = 2;
} 
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions here didn't work performantly for me.
My solution grabs the last line (not the first line, in my case it was not relevant to get the first or last line) from the file and removes that from that file.
This is very quickly even with very large files (>150000000 lines).

```
function file_pop($file)
{
    if ($fp = @fopen($file, "c+")) {
        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
            fclose($fp);
        }
        $pos = -1;
        $found = 0;
        while ($found < 2) {
            if (fseek($fp, $pos--, SEEK_END) < 0) { // can not seek to position
                rewind($fp); // rewind to the beginnung of the file
                break;
            };
            if (ord(fgetc($fp)) == 10) { // newline
                $found++;
            }
        }
        $lastpos = ftell($fp); // get current position of file
        $lastline = fgets($fp); // get current line

        ftruncate($fp, $lastpos); // truncate file to last position
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN); // unlock
        fclose($fp); // close the file

        return trim($lastline);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use file() method.

Gets the first line

```
$content = file('myfile.txt');
echo $content[0];
```

Comment: This worked great for me.  I have no idea why someone marked you down for it.  Thanks.  I tried to vote you up, but you're still at 0. :)

Comment: This method is highly inefficient against large files.

Comment: This does not remove the 1st line, it simply gets it.