# PHP text file cleared when using return statement

Tags: php, fopen, return

To start out with, I basically have a function that opens up a text file, grabs the first line, removes it from the file, and saves the file with the remainder. Everything is working fine except when I come to use the return statement to return the line retrieved. Using the return statement, for some reason it clears the file; removing the return statement, the function does what it's supposed to. I'm debating whether this is a PHP bug or if there's something hidden here that I'm not seeing. Parts of the code is listed below, any help will be immensely appreciated.

Thanks!

```
    $nlines = array();

    $lines  = file(CACHE_PATH."/test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $link  = $lines[0];

    $lcount = count($lines)-1;
    for($i=1; $i < $lcount; $i++)
    {
        $nlines[] = $lines[$i];
    }

    $file  = fopen(CACHE_PATH."/test.txt", 'w');

    for($i=0; $i <= $lcount; $i++)
    {
        fwrite($file, $nlines[$i]);
    }

    fclose($file);

    return $link;
```

Comment: Could you create a minimal test-case that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You realise that you're only adding `count($lines)-2` elements to `$nlines`, but you're trying to read `count($lines)` elements from it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404707/php-efficent-way-to-get-and-remove-first-line-in-file

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I understand I'm pretty much starting from 1 in the array but ending 2 before it by what I'm doing, but I don't see what you're getting at with the "read count() elements from it". The count is just to obtain  the number of elements in the array, using that, I can grab lines from the file according to the index $i into $nlines. Anyway, Sabeen Malik has a better solution to my approach, should have thought of it. Unfortunately though, this doesn't solve the issue with the return. I'll comment with a test-case scenario of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Here's the test-case scenario. 

`function example(){ 
    $lines = file("test.txt"); 
    $lnk = $lines[0]; 
    $file = fopen("test.txt", 'a'); 
    fwrite($file, "test text"); 
    fclose($file); 
    return $lnk; 
}`

 In the code above (haven't tested it, just wrote it) the first line of the file should be grabbed, the file should be cleared, and the text "test text" should be written. However, with the return statement in the function, the file is completely cleared, and the text written just disappears. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Comment: @Friday: I mean exactly that; you're reading from `0` to `$lcount` inclusive, and `$lcount = count($lines)-1`, so you're reading a total of `count($lines)` elements.  This is two more than you've actually written into this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems aright to me. However here is a simplified version. Its untested though:

```
function something(){

    $lines  = file(CACHE_PATH."/test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $link  = $lines[0];
    unset($lines[0]);

    $file  = fopen(CACHE_PATH."/test.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($file, implode("\n" , $lines) );
    fclose($file);

    return $link;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Haven't thought about approaching it this way to avoid the loops. Thanks. :) Unfortunately though, this doesn't fix the issue, the return statement still, for some reason causes the file's contents to completely wipe clean.

It's leaving me puzzled and wondering if this is a PHP related issue as a whole rather than with my code.
Thanks.

Comment: @Friday ok in that case why don't you try to save to test2.txt for test purposes and see what happens? also do a print_r($lines); after the `unset()` and see if there is actually any data in there afterwards. I am sure this is something trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave the test2.txt a try, it wrote without any erasing. So I went back and gave test.txt a try, and it wrote without erasing. It's the oddest thing, it just magically works now. I suppose something was hindering it, and it was removed when I rewrote the file path. Thanks for your help, it was greatly appreciated. =)