# Remove first line form file using php

Tags: php, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php - efficent way to get and remove first line in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404707/php-efficent-way-to-get-and-remove-first-line-in-file)

I need to remove first line form txt file using php. Could you show me example code how to do it? I know that it's easy but I don't know php:) Thanks!

Comment: If it's easy, then it should be easy to learn. stackoverflow revolves around helping people, not doing things for them.  On a more useful note though, you should find either substr and strpos, or explode and implode of use.

Comment: Make use of the search box in the upper-right corner of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$file = file_get_contents(SOME_FILE);
$arr = explode('\n\r', $file);
if (isset($arr[0])) unset ($arr[0]);
$string = implode('\n\r', $arr);
file_put_contents(SOME_FILE, $string);
```

Comment: Pretty sure if (isset($arr[0])) unset ($arr); is a typo.

Comment: Sorry newbie question, but it works not correct, it gives error  PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: arr in 1.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in 1.php on line 5  and removes everything from file.

Answer (score 2):

You could have used the search function at least. You would have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404707/php-efficent-way-to-get-and-remove-first-line-in-file):

```
$contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$first_line = array_shift($contents);
file_put_contents($file, implode("\r\n", $contents));
```